# estimating Fay Herriot model assumptions

Tags: small-area-estimation

I am estimating a Fay-Herriot model in a small area estimation using a survey data set with information on a current sample and information on the sample taken in the prior year. It is specified similarly to this notation

=++

here  is a direct estimator of a certain parameter , for a certain small area , =1,…, where the error terms are independent and normally distributed ∼(0,) and where , the sampling variance, is known. ∼(0,2) are the small area random effects and is known.

Generally, I am wondering why the linear mixed model is appropriate under the FH-model rather than ANOVA model. What are the assumptions that are different?

Comment: Hi. This is a MathJax-enabled site.
Please use this facility
to typeset your mathematical expressions for better legibility. For a quick 
guide, check this Meta
CV post: [Instructions on
how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated).